# in Jquery, How can I use If/else with window.location.pathname.indexOf?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, pathname

I have a website that is broken into 4 subcategories. each category contains html files that I would like to alter depending on the parent category. Basically, I want jquery to read the folder name of the HTML document and depending on the name, initiate a script.  I want each category to target a different class (which I why I need separate categories)  I've resolved on this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.workopen').click(function(e) {
    $(this).siblings('.open').addBack().toggleClass('open');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  if (window.location.pathname.indexOf("firstcategory") > -1) {
    $('.work .workopen .four').siblings('.open').addBack().toggleClass('open')
    $('.one .inner2, .two .inner2, .three .inner2').hide();
    $('.etc').css("text-decoration", "underline");
  }
});
```

it does exactly what I want! but only works on one category at a time (firstcategory). my question is: can I write an if/else statement that will allow me to alter three more categories? or do I have to write 4 seperate JS files?

Comment: Sure you can do an `if-else` statement.  I'd also recomment pulling the value of `window.location.pathname.indexOf("firstcategory")` into a variable first :)

Comment: I'm very new to JQuery/JS, could you show me how I would do that? I also forgot to mention that I want each category to target a different class (which I why I need separate categories)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First pull the path name into a variable.  Then you can simply use a series of `if-else` statements.

```
var pathName = window.location.pathname;

if (pathName.indexOf("firstcategory") > -1) {
    // what you want to show/hide
} else if (pathName.indexOf("secondcategory") > -1) {
    // what you want to show/hide
} else if (pathName.indexOf("thirdcategory") > -1) {
    // what you want to show/hide
} else if (pathName.indexOf("fourthcategory") > -1) {
    // what you want to show/hide
}
```

I would recommend just adding a single class to each operation you want to apply it to.  Elements may have more than one class :)

Answer (score 1):

The `switch` statement in javascript is tailor-made for your situation. Here's the strategy: Extract the part of window.location.pathname that matches one of 'firstcategory', 'secondcategory', etc., with a regular expression and use the switch statement:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.workopen').click(function(e) {
    $(this).siblings('.open').addBack().toggleClass('open');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  var matches = /(first|second|third|fourth)category/.exec(window.location.pathname);     
  switch (matches[0]){
     case 'firstcategory':
        $('.work .workopen    .four').siblings('.open').addBack().toggleClass('open')
        $('.one .inner2, .two .inner2, .three .inner2').hide();
        $('.etc').css("text-decoration", "underline");
        break;
     case 'secondcategory':
        // second category stuff
        break;
     case 'thirdcategory':
        // third category stuff
        break;
     case 'fourthcategory':
        // fourth category stuff
        break;
  }
});
```

Comment: Ah this one's pretty neat too! (wish I could vote up, but i'm still new here :/)  you guys are rad